# Quick edit List URL field

Tags: 2013, list, excel, custom-field-types, quick-edit

I need to use the *quick edit* on a **Link List** (I am copying data from an Excel file).
I am having trouble with the **URL field**, I can easly insert the URL but I don not know how to insert the **URL name**. (the name displayed instead of the url path). 
Is there a way to define this value into the quick edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have the PowerShell answer, but when I need to bulk upload links into a list I use the below formulas.  The Hyperlink Field formula works for a hyperlink field in a Links list, but I usually use a Custom List with a MLT field so the links open in a new tab.  While in Quick Edit, paste the cells with the formula into your list.

**MLT Field Formula**

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href=","""",[@[Link URL]],""""," ",[@[target="_blank">]],[@[Link Description]],"</a>")
```

[image]

**Hyperlink Field Formula**

```
=CONCATENATE("""",[Link URL],"""",", ","""",,[Link Description],"""")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no option for this in quick edit view. I was referring to Data Sheet view before. Which seems to be much different with the new quick edit implementation.

Please refer [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40b3a8e0-bfe2-418d-b0db-b6b7b2fe208d/pasting-hyperlinks-in-quick-edit-view) thread where a Technical Community Support member posted in Technet.

Comment: It says 'URL not valid'

Comment: Thanks, I m going by PowerShell, updating the TitleURl using the tilte of the item

Comment: The answer I posted before is the way how actually it is stored. so try putting that way in Powershell for 2-3 items. It might work.